# Install gitlab with docker using existing data

Tags: docker, gitlab, restore

I had a gitlab-docker instance which I didn't backup with the gitlab command but kept all volumes.

The docker container no longer exists and I need to bring up the gitlab instance although when I `docker-compose up -d` using the correct volumes gitlab still thinks its a new instance. Is there something I am missing? I tried updating permissions etc but with no success.

Is there a way to load "raw" data into gitlab? Ideally I want users, groups, repositories, issues.

Here's the docker-compose

`web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: '---
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url '----'
  volumes:
    - '/home/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/home/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/home/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker compose namespaces all non-external volumes. To reference an existing volume you can do the following:

Do a `docker volume ls` to find the volume name, and replace it below:

```
...
    volumes:
      - <volume-name>:/etc/gitlab

volumes:
  <volume-name>:
    external: true
```

**Update**: 
So the volumes are lost only the data is still there:

In that case, don't use data volumes, just use a [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) where you bind the data directories that you have directly onto the new container instance:

```
...
    volumes:
      - <absolute-location-to-data-director-on-host>:/etc/gitlab
      - ... Do same for the other volumes ...
```

Comment: well the think is that there no volumes anymore.. i just have the data that were inside the volumes.. This is what i kept.
Imagine i had one pc with gitlab running backed up the volumes.. then i transfer in new pc and want to restore this.

Comment: well  this is what i already did. but when gitlab starts its like its a new instance being installed.

Comment: ok this is embarrassing. i had a typo in my docker-compose and hence not pointing to the correct volumes. thanks for the answers,